# Encoding puzzles with sockets in different languages

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, sockets

I have this below code written in PHP responsible for the server socket, specifically by writing messages to certain sockets:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
const PAYLOAD_LENGTH_16 = 126;
const PAYLOAD_LENGTH_63 = 127;
const OPCODE_CONTINUATION  = 0;

for ($i = 0; $i < $frameCount; $i++) {
    // fetch fin, opcode and buffer length for frame
    $fin = $i != $maxFrame ? 0 : self::FIN;
    $opcode = $i != 0 ? self::OPCODE_CONTINUATION : $opcode;
    $bufferLength = $i != $maxFrame ? $bufferSize : $lastFrameBufferLength;

    // set payload length variables for frame
    if ($bufferLength <= 125) {
        $payloadLength = $bufferLength;
        $payloadLengthExtended = '';
        $payloadLengthExtendedLength = 0;
    }
    elseif($bufferLength <= 65535) {
        $payloadLength = self::PAYLOAD_LENGTH_16;
        $payloadLengthExtended = pack('n', $bufferLength);
        $payloadLengthExtendedLength = 2;
    } else {
        $payloadLength = self::PAYLOAD_LENGTH_63;
        $payloadLengthExtended = pack('xxxxN', $bufferLength); // pack 32 bit int, should really be 64 bit int
        $payloadLengthExtendedLength = 8;
    }

    // set frame bytes
    $buffer = pack('n', (($fin | $opcode) << 8) | $payloadLength).$payloadLengthExtended.substr($message, $i * $bufferSize, $bufferLength);
```

And below I have the code in Objective-C responsible for receiving these messages from the socket server:

```
NSInteger len = 0;

        uint8_t buffer[4096];
        while ([inputStream hasBytesAvailable]) {
            len = [inputStream read:buffer maxLength:sizeof(buffer)];
            if (len > 0) {
                [self.data appendBytes:buffer length:len];
                [self.log insertText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Log: Received a message from server:\n\n"]];
                NSLog(@"Received a message from server...");
            }
        }
```

when all bytes are received I run the following command to turn the data into a file:

```
[self.data writeToFile:@"dataComes.txt" options:NSDataWritingAtomic error:nil]
```

**The Problem**

We will send a large file in JSON format for objective-c, with that he will receive that information and will generate a file called `dataComes.txt`, I can see the JSON file normally but except for some strange characters such as:

```
~ or ~Â or â-Û
```

These strange characters always shows at the beginning of each block messages that Objective-C receives (Yes, the socket server and TCP divide large messages into blocks of messages).

What is the cause of this problem and how it could solve this?

Answer (score 1):

> SOLUTION 1: Filtering

I can filter out unwanted characters that may come, but it will also filter out some words that have accentuation:

```
NSCharacterSet *notAllowedChars = [[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[]{}:,'"] invertedSet];
NSString *resultString = [[total componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:notAllowedChars] componentsJoinedByString:@" "];
```

> SOLUTION 2: Stop using sockets

I have tried many ways to send data to my app, the only one that worked was to send the data separately (a loop of one JSON), but to works I had to put my code (PHP) to sleep using `sleep(1)` (and I believe this is not good) because if not Objective-C recognizes that this data is a single package.

In this case, or my code have problems, or the programming of socket in objective-c was not very well done and has inconsistencies (bug). What remains for me to do with my connections through normal requests via web server (which I do not think it's a good idea, since I have to do this every 3 seconds in a 5 minute time interval).

> SOLUTION 3: FILTERING + UNICODE

On the server side I can filter all special characters and create a specific combination for it example:

> `Hello é world` to `Hello /e001/ world`

And in my app I can filter this combination and change to the real format....